# Connect different html elements using canvas line

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, html5-canvas

[Tree Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHbKK.png)

[image]

Is it possible to draw line between HTML elements using canvas and angularJS.

As we can see in above image.

Comment: I have made static nodes for family member and trying to draw lines between them for their relationship

Comment: It can be done on entirely on canvas. The nodes are simple (`context.arc` with `context.fillText`). Connectors are simple to draw (`context.lineTo`), but if you don't want the connectors to overlap nodes/other connectors then you must add a complex pathfinding algorithm like the [traveling salesman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). If you want html nodes then you might consider SVG connectors instead of canvas.